# Where can I find DSL documentations for a Jenkins plugin?

Tags: jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl, jenkins-2

Im working with Jenkins DSL and pipelines. Where can I find DSL documentations for these plugins I've typically used GUIs to configure?

I find it hard to imagine that when a new plugin is published that it already supports DSL. (Or are they written in DSL?). Is there a way to find this documentation? Is there an example of a walkthrough to enumerate this?

Or is DSL support limited to 'first class citizen' plugins.

Some of the plugins I am using are azure, packer,     maven. It's not the DSL documentation I am asking about, but going about hunting for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't really a centralized place (that I know of) for this, as each plugin will publish its documentation differently.

In terms of where you can search:

- Some plugin steps can be found on the [jenkins.io website](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/).
- http://your-jenkins/pipeline-syntax for generated syntax for your version of Jenkins and plugin versions
- The source code, since most Jenkins plugins are open source